# When to use ngAttr?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-interpolate

Just wanted some clarifications. I was told that you are suppose to use ngAttr when there are interpolated markup. For example:

```html
<div ng-attr-name={{Name}}></div>
```

I also seen some codes online where there are interpolated markups but they do not use ngAttr. Are there certain situations when you use ngAttr and not use ngAttr when dealing with interpolated markups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall running into this issue when working with `<svg/>` and attempting to interpolate attributes such as cx (which happens to be the classic example in the current angularjs documentation). The browser will complain when you attempt the following:

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="{{cx}}"></circle>
</svg>
```

due to restrictions when using the SVG DOM API. Therefore, the `ng-attr` directive comes in handy with

```
<svg>
  <circle ng-attr-cx="{{cx}}"></circle>
</svg>
```

As a result, using the `ng-attr- directive in this scenario will appropriately set the value based on your binding. Now, what I have noticed new in the documentation are the following cases that have known to cause issues if you don't use ng-attr

> - size in  elements (see [issue 1619](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1619))
> - placeholder in  in Internet Explorer 10/11 (see [issue 5025](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025))
> - type in  in Internet Explorer 11 (see [issue 14117](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5025))
> - value in  in Internet Explorer = 11 (see [issue 7218](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7218))

Comment: Awesome, this is really helpful! I appreciate the explanation as well as the related issues.